# How to model 2 tables recursive relation in Prisma or raw Postrgres

Tags: postgresql, relationship, prisma, data-modeling

I got a problem to do my data model on a quite tricky relationship that I had not seen until now :
I have two entities : templates and variables.
A Template is a mathematical expression which can contain variables.
For example sqrt(1+a), here the variable is "a".
A variable can be a number or another template, let's say that the second template is 1/b.
So now the complete math expression is sqrt(1+(1/b)).
Variable "b" now can be a number or another variable.
Etc.
This structure allows to describe nested expressions.

Is someone have an idea of how to model this structure in prisma (I thought about explicit many to many relationship between two entities) and if it is not feasable in raw postgres ?
I have to be able to get the entire expression getting recursively templates -> their variables -> their templates -> their variables, etc